# Is it possible to debug the system .NET DLL's as unoptimized?

Tags: .net, debugging

I'm trying to debug some code in the .NET Framework. Unfortunately, many of the variables are optimized away, and I can't reliably set the instruction pointer due to flow optimizations.

Is it possible to force the runtime to NOT use the ngen'd versions of the .NET system DLL's, but instead use the MSIL, forcing optimization to 'off'?

Note: I've tried using the INI trick to set AllowOptimize=false but it made no difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got the answer from John Robbins. Basically, stick COMPLUS_ZapDisable=1 in your env vars (wrap in a bat to avoid running the whole system unoptimized) and disable the VS hosting process.

http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/29/how-to-disable-optimizations-when-debugging-reference-source.aspx

Another option is the new .NET Reflector Pro that lets you selectively decompile/recompile assemblies unoptimized. Not necessary with reference source but a good backup.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/features_pro.htm

Comment: Do you know how to make this work with ASP.NET? The IIS process is not launched from VS, so it likely won't get affected by the env variable.

Answer (score 12):

Here's another option (from http://martin.bz/asp-net-mvc-source-debugging-the-easy-way):

> Go to the directory where System.Web.Mvc .dll is located:
>
> c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\
>
> Create the file System.Web.Mvc.ini
>
> ```
> [.NET Framework Debugging Control]
> GenerateTrackingInfo=1
> AllowOptimize=0
> ```
>
> Next time you step into the MVC source code you can inspect all
>   variables.

More details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8z24x.aspx

Comment: To apply this technique to any other assembly in general, locate the folder by attaching a VS debugger and opening: DEBUG > Windows > Modules.

Comment: Mine (Windows 10) is at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_4.0.0.1__31bf3856ad364e35

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you see the code of .NET framework itself with [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx)? Reflector enables you to see the code of any .NET assembly [including the .NET framework itself!], and even recompile it! -- Of course this applies to non-obfuscated assemblies!

Comment: I'm already stepping through Microsoft's source directly using their reference source server. I've used Reflector to recompile simple assemblies in the past, but the system DLL's are often a mix of native and managed. They're also signed which will probably prevent me from overriding their internal references.